# Hibernate populate parent id to child during saving

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an entity Order who declares `@ManyToMany` relationship.

`@ManyToMany` is represented by a separate entity with a link to Order.
When I create the instance of Order I can't save `@ManyToMany` because I'm getting `order_id cannot be null`.
So I saved Order entity separately from `@ManyToMany`, created `@ManyToMany` object, then saved it through own repository, but now I can't attach this `@ManyToMany` to the Order object.
And when I find Order - it has a null collection of `@ManyToMany`.

How to update Orders with `@ManyToMany`?

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is unclear, but I'll assume you need to make sure to set your associations right before saving.

Let's assume your other class is called `OtherClass`. It should have a method called "addOrder", that you need to call before saving it with a repository/dao.

```
@Entity
public class OtherClass {

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Order> orders;

    public void addOrder(Order order) {
        orders.add(order);
        order.getOthers().add(this);
    }
}
```